# Move to the label in new page

Tags: html, label, href

I want to go to label in another page. I know that I can use

```
<a href="#top"> Top </a>
```

to move in one page to

`<div name='top'> </div>`

Can I use something like `<a href="/newpage#top"> Top </a>`

to move to the label in any other?(this example is not working)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code below:

```
<a href="/newpage.html#top">top</a>

<div id="top" name="top"></div>
```

I have added id="top" to the div which calls name="top".

Comment: It worked, but something strange happened. First it showed the anchor place and then jumped to the beginning of the page!(

Comment: may be try calling a different name instead of 'top' and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any framework like backbones js or angular???? otherwise you may be missing the extension of newpage . for eg.

```
<a href="/newpage.html#top">Top</a>
```

Also try adding the id attribute i.e #top to your div.